# Find records included in range of numbers (min - max)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Course.rb**

```
min_age: integer
max_age: integer
```

Student age comes from `params[:age]` - for example 15, that means student is 15 years old and he looks for courses that will cover his age:

I have courses:

```
id    min_age   max_age
------------------------
1     5          15
2     10         25
3     10         55
4     20         40
```

**Question:**

How can I find all records where min_age and max_age covers the age param value? If student says he is 15 years old the courses he should see is:

1, 2, and 3 as these are the ones who covers this age.

More, I need to use this in search model that creates a search record when when someone searches for courses and the results returned back are users (tutors who offer these courses).

```
  def find_courses
    users = User.joins(:courses).where("courses.lesson ILIKE ?", "%#{lesson}%")
    # failed attempt:
    users = users.where('course.min_age >= :age or courses.max_age <= :age', age: age)
  end
```

Thank you for your time.

**Based on accepted answer:**

```
Course.where('min_age <= :age AND max_age >= :age', age: 18)
```

the above sql will require for both conditions to be true in order to display the record:

```
id    min_age   max_age
------------------------
1     5  true  + 15 false = false
2     10 true  + 25 true  =  true
3     10 true  + 55 true  =  true
4     20 false + 40 true  =  false
```

That will return records with id: 2 and 3

Comment: Shouldn't it be an `and` in the condition instead of `or`?

Comment: well, it will look for both condition to be true I guess and will return nothing as result, unless he finds an exact record.. I remember I tried it once and it didn't worked.

Comment: Between queries actually mean that you are looking for an upper limit as well as lower limit. For eg. `5 <= 15 <= 15` holds true, wherein `5 <= 15` *AND* `15 <= 15` both hold true.

Comment: see the updated answer lower, I posted a reply from my console to @rails4guides.com that covers your example with and

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the greater than/less than symbols and use AND

```
Course.where('min_age <= :age AND max_age >= :age', age: 18)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, does that means that both conditions should be true in order to return it as a result?

Comment: This should return course 2 and 3 from you question. course 2 has min_age at 10 so in the query min_age has to be less than or equal to 18. Same goes for max_age, but it has to greater than 18. You had it opposite so with 18, you said "give me a course that has a min_age that is greater than 18 and max_age that is less than 18". Of course that returns []

Comment: Perfect answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be

```
def find_courses
  user_courses = User.joins(:courses).where('courses.lesson ILIKE ?', "%#{lesson}%")
  user_courses.where(':age >= courses.min_age and :age <= courses.max_age', age: age)
end
```

Comment: This will work too, the same as accepted one, just switched places between argument and attribute. Andreas was 1 min ahead of you ;)  Thanks.

Comment: That's fine. I thought earlier that the comments would be enough. When they weren't, I decided to write the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

By implementing the resource in a more Rails like way, the structure will allow easy querying:

in routes.rb:

```
resources :users, only: :show do
  resources :courses, only: :index
end
```

in CoursesController#index:

```
@courses = current_user.available_courses
```

in User model:

```
def available_courses
  Course.where('min_age <= ? and max_age >= ?', age, age)
end
```

Also in the way of logic and reusability I suggest giving a User a date_of_birth:datetime attribute and setting a method in the User model to return it's age.

Comment: User in my case is a tutor who creates a course, I don't care about his birthdate, student is a person who will not register into the app, just use it to search a course and he will put it in his age, integer value. Thank you.